# can variable declared in main be accessed from static function?

Tags: java, variables, static-methods

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    static int simpleArraySum(int n, int[] ar) {
        // Complete this function
        for(int ar_i = 0; ar_i < n; ar_i++){
            result = result +ar[ar_i];
            return result;  
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();
        int[] ar = new int[n];
        for(int ar_i = 0; ar_i < n; ar_i++){
            ar[ar_i] = in.nextInt();
        }
         int result = simpleArraySum(n, ar);
         System.out.println(result);

    }
}
```

> error log

```
Solution.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
            result = result +ar[ar_i];
            ^
  symbol:   variable result
  location: class Solution
Solution.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
            result = result +ar[ar_i];
                     ^
  symbol:   variable result
  location: class Solution
Solution.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
            return result;
                   ^
  symbol:   variable result
  location: class Solution
3 errors
```

This program is suppose to print the sum of the elements in an array. i have no idea how to access variable declared in main from the static function. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: The scope of `int result` is limited to the `main` method. Even if these two are `static`, the variable is inside the method. You could declare `static int result` in the class instead.

Comment: declare the variable result

Comment: @AxelH thanks the solution you provided also works out. cheers have a good day!

Comment: @JavaLearner1 thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `result` does not exists in `simpleArraySum()` method because it is defined in the scope of the main

You may create a variable in the method which will do the sum and return it, and it will be stored in `result` int the main

Also you need to put the `return sum;` AFTER the loop, if you don't, it will do the 1st iteration and then return the result and it's the end, you need to do all the loop and after return the sum, like this :

```
static int simpleArraySum(int n, int[] ar) {
    int sum = 0;
    for(int ar_i = 0; ar_i < n; ar_i++){
        sum = sum +ar[ar_i];      
    }
    return sum;
}
```

---

**Tips** (you don't need to use them, they are only *INFORMATIVE*):

you can also use a `for each loop`, which means *for each int in the array ar, called `intInLoop` we'll do this*

```
for (int intInLoop : ar){
      sum = sum + i;
}
```

And `sum = sum +ar[ar_i];` is same as `sum += ar[ar_i];`

Comment: Thanks @azro for helping me out. I will certainly use the tips that you have mentioned. cheers have a good day!